# Progress bar in Windows 8 XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml

Would be really helpful if someone could tell me which event handler I need to use when a webpage is/has loaded using **Windows 8.1**, as well as the C# code for making the web page progress show up in the progress bar.

EDIT: Apologies if this isn't clear. This is for windows store apps rather than windows forms. I'm coding with C#, and i'm wondering how to implement the progressbar to the webbrowser(webview) so that it is updated dependent on the progress of the loading page.

Thanks.

Comment: if this is XAML then no, you're not supposed to be using events for this. Bind the `Value` property of the ProgressBar to some relevant `int` or `double` property in the ViewModel. Still, your question is completely unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these answers:

[WPF WebBrowser: How I do access progress and new window events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063855/wpf-webbrowser-how-i-do-access-progress-and-new-window-events)

[Determine if WPF WebBrowser is loading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767632/determine-if-wpf-webbrowser-is-loading-a-page)

If you are with no time, you can simply put a Indeterminate Progress bar, until you code a refinated Progress code.

```
<ProgressBar Name="pb1" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="True" />

void theBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("Webpage Loaded !!");
    pb1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```